# $\int \frac{ax^2 + 2bx + c}{(Ax^2 + 2Bx + C)^2} dx $ (where $B^2\ne AC$) is a rational function then which of the condition must satisfy

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, rational-functions

The options given are

(a) $2Bb = Ac + aC$

(b) $Aa + Bb = Cc$

(c) $Bb = aC + cA$

(d) $abA + cbC = 2Bac$

My attempt :

I assumed the above integral as $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)} $and differentiated both sides with respect to $x$.

So we get

$\frac{ax^2 + 2bx + c}{(Ax^2 + 2Bx + C)^2} $ =$ \frac{q(x).p'(x) - q'(x).p(x)}{q(x)^2}$   (quotient rule)

By comparison $q(x) = Ax^2 + 2Bx + C$

And assuming $p(x) = lx^2 + mx + n$

I get an expression for $l$ ,$m$ and $n$. (I don't see how it helps)

Is this the way to go? Or is there a better method?

Comment: That’s a good start. You could now compare the coefficients to get $p(x)$ in terms of the known constants.

Comment: That is exactly what I did.. I got an expression for l, m and n in terms of the known constants, but how should I proceed afterwards??

Comment: @MeetPatel solve for $l$, $m$, and $n$. That would give you the answer you want. Another thing to consider is that the top of quotient rule would technically give a third degree polynomial, so either the third degree coefficient needs to cancel out, or our assumption of $p$ being a second degree polynomial is incorrect (it could be both, I suspect $p$ should be first degree because asymptotically the derivative behaves as $x^{-2}$ so the antiderivative might asymptotically behave as $x^{-1}$). Try plugging in a general polynomial like a sum and see what happens.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I am saying it again! I solved for l, m and n but what should I do next after solving for l, m and n? How do I get the conditions? And btw P satisfies as a 2 degree polynomial as the 3rd degree term gets cancelled..

Comment: @MeetPatel Why don't you show your expressions for $l,m,n$ Is it possible that they cannot be satisfied unless one of the conditions given is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polynomial $p(x)$ should be of degree (at most) one: $p(x)=mx+n$. From
$$
m(Ax^2+2Bx+C)-(mx+n)(2Ax+2B)=ax^2+2bx+c
$$
you get a linear system in two unknowns, with *three* equations.

Thus you will get a relation between $a,b,c$ and $A,B,C$. Solve two equations for $m$ and $n$ and substitute in the third one.

If you try with a (formally) degree $2$ polynomial $p(x)=lx^2+mx+n$, you get
$$
p'(x)q(x)-p(x)q'(x)=(2Bl- Am)x^2 + (2Cl - 2An)x + (Cm - 2Bn)
$$

```
? (2*l*x+m)*(A*x^2+2*B*x+C)-(l*x^2+m*x+n)*(2*A*x+2*B)
%1 = (2*B*l - A*m)*x^2 + (2*C*l - 2*n*A)*x + (C*m - 2*n*B)
```

This leads to the linear system
\begin{cases}
2Bl-Am=a \\[4px]
2Cl-2An=2b \\[4px]
Cm-2Bn=c
\end{cases}
Multiply the first equation by $C$, the second equation by $B$ and subtract to get
$$
ACm-2ABn=2bB-aC
$$
From the third equation you get then $Ac=2bB-aC$. Solving for $l$ yields $l=0$.

Comment: I do get the answer by assuming p(x) to be linear, but I don't think you can say that it must be linear because if I am assuming it as a quadratic the term of x^3 gets cancelled, and as it gets cancelled I get 3 relations with 3 variables unlike 3 relations with 2 variables where I assume p(x) as linear and can use the third to get the condition required..

Comment: @MeetPatel that means you completely ignored the reasoning given earlier for why $p$ must be linear.

Comment: @MeetPatel So what? Try as I did and you'll realize that degree one is what you're looking for (and that comes from other considerations as well).